# Why can't I configure springboot actuator through environment variables when targeting GraalVM

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, graalvm

I am updating some Springboot applications to run on GraalVM images.

These applications run on Kubernetes and it uses actuator's probes to check their status. To avoid exposing the actuator endpoints I change the management server port via the `MANAGEMENT_SERVER_PORT` environment variable.

Doing so works great in a non native context but with a native image (using `native-maven-plugin`) the `MANAGEMENT_SERVER_PORT` is ignored. But for example passing `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` works as expected. Also configuring the port by setting `management.server.port` in the properties file works fine.

Here is a basic example to reproduce the issue https://github.com/adrien-ben/springboot-native-actuator-env-var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35288.

Setting the management port changes beans which can only happen at build time.

As a workaround setting the `management.server.port` property to a default value
sets up the beans for separate management port which can then be overriden at runtime with the `MANAGEMENT_SERVER_PORT` env var.